# How can I activate wifi on VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest, and Windows 10 as a host. I remember clearly being able to use wifi right away when I first installed it about a year ago on my virtual machine without any configuration. Sometime later I switched to wired network, and I guess at that time I configured the interfaces file to those settings.

I have not used my Linux system for a while, but now I am back and have to use it for a server. I surfed several online manuals. What they are proposing is to go to Network settings on VB, on Adapter 1 tab select Bridged network and for the name choose my network adapter and also to check the Cabled connection checkbox. After this it should work as to those manuals, but it's not working in my case.

Should I change something in the interfaces file or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved guys!

I have deleted all my previous entries in the interfaces file.
Wrote the default values I found online as follows:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Hey the story goes on.
After some headscratching I found that I should replace the `eth0` entries `enp0s3` and eventually it worked. So my current interfaces file reads:

```
 # The loopback network interface
    auto lo enp0s3
    iface lo inet loopback

 # The primary network interface
    iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```